# form submission not working when trying to send an email in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a simple system to keep patient records. I have added  a patient to the system and now i have created a view to retrieve patient name and email address from the system (GET method) and is working. The challenge is sending an email to the selected patient using the patient's registered email address with some additional information that is Subject and Body of the email from a form on form submission (POST method) is not working. the form is not being submitted. I have send some emails before using the same EmailForm from forms.py in  a different view and is working.

here is my views.py

```
def send_client_mail(request, pk):

    patient = Patient.objects.get(id=pk)
    address = patient.email

    if request.method == "POST":
        form= EmailForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data.get('subject')
            address = address
            message = form.cleaned_data.get('email_body')
            send_mail(
                name,
                message,
                'myemailaddress@gmail.com',
                [address, ],
                fail_silently=False)
            messages.info(request, 'Email was sent successfully !!')

    else:
        form = EmailForm(None)
    return render(request, 'client_email.html', {'title': 'send email to ', 'form': form, 'patients': patient)
```

here is my forms.py

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Email subject', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'40',
                                                                         'style':'font-size:medium'}))
    email_address = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Recepient Email Address', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'40',
                                                                         'style':'font-size:medium'}))
    email_body = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Email body/message', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'size':'10',
                                                                         'style':'font-size:medium;', 'rows' :4}))

    def clean_subject(self):
        subject = self.cleaned_data.get('subject')
        if subject == "":
            raise ValidationError('subject cannot be empty')
        else:
            return subject

    def clean_email_address(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email_address')
        if email == "":
            raise ValidationError('email address cannot be empty')
        else:
            return email

    def clean_email_body(self):
        message = self.cleaned_data.get('email_body')
        if message == "":
            raise ValidationError('Please provide the email message you want to send!')
        else:
            return message
```

here is my Html Template

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 d-flex flex-column mt-3 mb-2" style="margin:auto; align-items:center; justify-content:center">
           <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-9">
                       <h4 class="">Send Email to {{ patients.email }}</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-3">
                     <a href="{% url 'alerts' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Back to Alerts menu</a>
                 </div>
             </div>
               <hr class="my-4">
           </div>
              {% for message in messages %}
                <div  class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" role="alert" style="color:#0e466b;"> {{ message }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
           <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-12">
                {{ form.subject|as_crispy_field }}
           </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-12">
                {{ form.email_body|as_crispy_field }}
           </div>
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

        <button  class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" > send email</button>
                 <hr class="my-4">
            </div>
         </div>


</form>
```

I don't have an idea why the form is not submitting and the email not sending.

Comment: What browser are you using? The issue may be you are using some browser which doesn't have the default button type of submit (Internet explorer etc.). Always specify the button type when using one. Try adding `type="submit"` on your button tag.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: I have added `type="submit" ` but still it's not working

Comment: Your form has the field `email_address` also, yet you don't render and use it. Although you set `required=False` but you also implement a `clean_email_address` where you raise a `ValidationError` if it is empty. This causes `form.is_valid()` to return `False`.